# Wpf, I need to hide and show a groupbox?

Tags: wpf, hide, show

How I can show or hide a groupbox from xaml.cs. I try to do this in the checkbox's event:

```
private void cbDaily_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    gbCalendar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But this don't work.

Comment: can you show us the XAML of that checkbox and groupbox?

Answer (score 3):

It must be work on checked/unchecked events of checkbox like this way :

```
private void chkTest_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     grpTest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

private void chkTest_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     grpTest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

It is working fine in my sample application. Can you please give more details of your problem, so I can have better idea. Is event fired properly ? Make sure name of groupbox in code behind is correct or not ?

Comment: Really visibility works different, this a sample that help me http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/